# Trouble with MediaElement in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm having difficulty with the `MediaElement` control in Silverlight for Windows Phone 7. My goal is to play two tones when the user presses a button. The method of doing this that I came up with is to have a `MediaElement` for each tone. (Is there possibly a better way?)

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="MediaElementTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

            <MediaElement 
                x:Name="firstTone"
                MediaEnded="firstTone_MediaEnded"
                Source="{Binding FirstTone}" />
            <MediaElement 
                x:Name="secondTone"
                Source="{Binding SecondTone}" />
            <Button Content="Play" Click="Button_Click" />

    </StackPanel>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Uri FirstTone
        {
            get
            {
                return new Uri("A.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }

        public Uri SecondTone
        {
            get
            {
                return new Uri("B.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            firstTone.Stop();
            secondTone.Stop();

            firstTone.Play();
        }

        private void firstTone_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            secondTone.Play();
        }
    }
```

When I click the button, no tone plays. Why is this? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all sorts of weird things going with URI's and their locations relative to the Silverlight application; and data-bindings are notoriously difficult to get right.  My recommendation would be to start troubleshooting this by hard-coding the absolute URI's to the MP3 files directly in the XAML.  Once you've got that working, switch to relative URI's, and when that's working, switch to data-binding them to the code-behind (or ViewModel or whatever).

If you've got the file placed in Isolated Storage, something like this ought to work (haven't tested it on WP7):

```
var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
var iStream = store.OpenFile("a.mp3", System.IO.FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
firstTone.SetSource(iStream);
firstTone.Play();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the absolute URIs would be in a WP7 app. You don't mean "c:\path\to\project\a.mp3", do you?

Comment: For a WP7 app, yeah, start with where they're actually at on the phone's file system.

Comment: what is the absolute path of a file in isolated storage for my app on the WP7?

Comment: Edited my answer above to give an example.  Basically, you use SetSource() instead of Source={}.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `MediaElement` for this. Instead add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll` (yes, even in a Silverlight Project) and then using [SoundEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb195053.aspx).

Something Like:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("a.mp3"))
{
    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    effect.Play();

    // This will pause while the first sound plays
    //  so they don't play over each other but as it also blocks!
    Thread.Sleep(effect.Duration);
}

using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("b.mp3"))
{
    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    effect.Play();
}
```

Comment: FYI. I've only used wav files for this method previously. Check your MP3 file format against the details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: @Rosarch It will block the current thread. Could run this off the UI and try invoking the playing on to the UI if need be.

Comment: The XNA SoundEffect and SoundEffectInstance only work with wav files when used in a Silverlight project.

Comment: @Walt Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes, it's in the MSDN docs, I looked before commenting but couldn't find it. I saw it this morning while researching another question.

Comment: OK, I found it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx

Comment: @Walt: I loved the extra restrictions they added - there aren't a whole lot of WAV files out there that aren't mono or stereo, 8 or 16 bits, and less than 8000 or greater than 48000 Hz.

Comment: @MusiGenesis, Plus, the Wav file have to be marked as resources, not as content.  Which slows down startup time loading your dll.

Comment: FWIW I've got a article about Audio and Windows phone coming out in CoDe magazine [not sure which issue yet]. I wrote about it because it can be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The MediaElement is intended for playing one piece of media at a time.  As others have mentioned, use the SoundEffect or SoundEffectInstance classes for simulaneous sounds.   You can play up to 16 SoundEffects at a time.

Also, using MediaElement can cause troubles with certification if you aren't careful.  If you set the MediaElement source in your XAML, for instance, it will cause any currently playing media on the phone to stop.   Unless you ask for user permission to stop playing media you will fail certification.

Comment: I think the asker intended for the two tones to be played consecutively, rather than simultaneously.

Comment: yeah, I wanted consecutive tones

Comment: Be aware that when playing two media files in MediaElement consecutively there will be a time gap between the two samples. There is no gapless playback on the phone.

Comment: This is happened to me - failed cert because of MediaElement source in my XAML. Your post here was the only thing I found on all of the interwebs that stated this - the failed cert report didn't do so. Do you know where this might be documented anywhere?

Comment: What's the appropriate way to use MediaElement without failing certification?

Comment: @Martin, You can read more about windows phone audio and certification in my Code Magazine article.
http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=1109071

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're hearing nothing at all, but if you want to hear two consecutive tones when the user clicks a button, why not just combine the tones ahead of time into a single file, and then just play that?

Comment: The two tones to play will not be known until runtime. (If I were to pre-make all the possible combinations, it would be a great deal of files. I'd rather do it programmatically.)

Comment: Oh, OK. I'll leave my answer up so nobody else makes the same suggestion.

Comment: My guess is there's something wrong with your Uris. I'd suggest finding a code sample online that works, and then modifying that gradually.

Answer (score 0):

I've never been able to get multiple MediaElements to work on a phone app.  I see the same problems as you, I can't play the media.

I believe that you can only have one active, but I haven't seen documention to that effect.  The way I've worked around it is to have one MediaElement defined in App.XAML

```
 <!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <MediaElement
        x:Key='mediaElement' AutoPlay='True' Source='/music/GroovinIntro.wav'/>
</Application.Resources>
```

and then expose it as a property on the Application class.

```
    public MediaElement MediaElement
{
  get
  {
    return this.Resources["mediaElement"] as MediaElement;
  }
}
```

Then call the MediaElement like this.

```
App.Current.MediaElement.Source = new Uri(_musicLocation, UriKind.Relative);
```